# python multiprocessing pool works on one machine and hangs forever on another

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I am running a simple multiprocessing code using `Pool` and `map` on Python 3.4 (Windows):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
p = Pool(6) 
result = p.map(f,args)
```

`args` is a list of integers. `f` is a nested function that is slicing a data matrix using only columns specified in `args` and runs one of the ML algorithms from `sklearn` on it. `f` is constructed using `partial` from a corresponding function of multiple arguments.

The code is working on the first machine but hangs forever on the second (actually 4 times more powerful) in file threading.py on line 284:

```
waiter.acquire()
```

The specification of machines' processors: 1) Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2603 @1.80GHz (2 processors); 2) Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 0 @2.7GHz

Can you help me to figure out why the code is hanging and how to make it work on another machine?

Comment: What else is different between the machines? This is not a lot of information to go on...

Comment: This is far from a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that will help others diagnose the issue. A starter would be what `f` effectively does to `args` and the data structure of `args`, which we may be able to infer based on `f`. Also differences between python versions, and python packages. Which can be found with `pip freeze > packages.txt`.

Comment: Its fairly clear there is a deadlock, and since the machine that hangs lists only one CPU, it is most likely a deadlock caused by acquiring one resource before locking, then waiting until the next resource is available, with multiple threads in that state, never giving up the locked resource.  However, that's about the limit of diagnosis based on what you have provided.  Please provide code.